# MvxRecyclerView does not update after resuming from background

Tags: android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a MvxRecyclerView that gets filtered by a SearchView and ordered by options in a PopupMenu. If I background the app and resume it, changing options in the PopupMenu does not re-order the items in the MvxRecyclerView as it does before backgrounding but the SearchView filters fine without ordering.

Comment: After backgrounding, when you choose an item in the popup menu does theOrderItems method get called at all - if you set a breakpoint does it hit? It sounds like your bindings aren't being rehydrated when you come back to the app from background. Can you provide the code for the layout (axml) and the Activity code?

Comment: It does get called and the MvxObservableCollection gets updated.
 
I thought maybe NotifyDataSetChanged wasn't being called on the Adapter but manually calling it in the Fragment's OnMenuItemClick does nothing. Also tried Invalidating the MvxRecyclerView with no change.

I'll add the layout and fragment code.

Comment: @pnavk Added the code.

Comment: Can you try removing the following `if (savedInstanceState != null) return _layout;`. I think this might be the problem as the old layout may be referencing outdated bindings

Comment: No change. The problem doesn't seem to be with the bindings as filtering through the SearchView works even after resuming from the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to solve a different issue this one got fixed.

I noticed FragmentInventoryTabView's OnResume was being called multiple times every time it came back from the background, which meant the ViewModel and the View were being instanced on every resume. They were being built with Mvx.IoCProvider.IoCConstruct() in the tab layout root ViewModel's ctor, so I changed those calls to  Mvx.IoCProvider.GetSingleton() and registered the ViewModel types as singletons in the MvxAppStart.

Now I can order the items in the MvxRecyclerView after resuming back from the background. But OnResume is still being called multiple times.